# How can I get Trendline Value from Syncfusion Chart

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

I want to get the value of Trendline.

In the picture, I can see the value at graph line, but I can't see Trendline value.

How can I get the trendline value?

I will calculate the diffrence.

[image: Chart image Link]

I want to get the Trendline value.

And I calculate difference.